# JDBC select query monitor

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, jdbc

I have encrypted password and stored into mysql table,actually couple of table are there to store different user credentials but column name(PASSWORD) is same in all tables.
      There are so many scenario's are there in my project to connect different servers with user credentials.So My requirement is rather than decrypt password in all places(after select statement), need to decrypt in a common area ,it could be Listener or some thing.
      When PASSWORD column find in select statement need to decrypt password.

please suggest how to achieve?

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: Need a listener that should fire when extracted data from result set.So by result set metadata will check whether PASSWORD column is there or not.If exists then decrypt passwod

Comment: Even AOP without spring also fine